Deno 2 Vscode debug start raising a lot of js errors
I have a nodejs express service that we started to use Deno 2. its run ok launching from a bash script but Im starting to try to run in Vscode debug (launch.json).
I make the initial configuration like said in the deno page https://docs.deno.com/runtime/reference/vscode/ and I added some skipfiles to ignore node_internals, node_modules.
but when I ran the debug mode start pausing with a lot of exceptions from inside node modules or files like 00_infra.js.
Some of these ones are:
00_infra.js -> No such file or directory (os error 2): Istat '/.dockerenv'
util.mjs -> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/.dockerenv'
00_infra.js -> Not found: proto error: no records fround for query { name: Name("uri-mongodb"), query_type: AAAA, query_class: IN) At async Object.resolveDns (ext: denot_net/01_net.js:77:12)
If I press F5 (continue) quickly to these errors the service at least run and show that connect to mongodb.
Im not sure why this happens when from a bash script run ok. The script simple load an .env file and run deno task dev, that this run a task from deno.json deno run --watch --allow-* src/server.ts
If anyone has a clue I would really appreciate it a lot!
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {
                "MY_ENV_VAR": "value"
            },
            "runtimeExecutable": "/path/to/deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--inspect-wait",
                "--allow-all"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.deno/**/*.js"
            ],
            "outputCapture": "std"
        }
    ]
}


These error are happening if the MONGO_URI is set, is empty no error happens but the connection to the DB, of course, is failing.

Solution that work for me (might some skips are duplicate):
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--inspect-wait",
                "--allow-all"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.deno/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.deno/**/node_modules/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.jsx",
                "**/connection_wrap.ts",
                "**/*.mjs"
            ],
            "outputCapture": "std"
        }
    ]
}

If anyone have a better solution please shared!
I hope this help someone else and don't spend some hours fighting!
